# illegal forward reference in java

Tags: java

```
 import java.io.*;
 import jxl.*;
 class Xlparsing
 {
   Workbook wb =wb.getWorkbook(new File(
    "C:\\Documents and Settings\\kmoorthi\\Desktop\\ak\\new.xls"));
   // Illegal forward reference What it means
   Sheet st = wb.getSheet(0);
   Cell cell1 = st.getCell(0,0);
   String a1 = cell1.getContents();
   public static void main(String s[])
   {
     System.out.println(new Xlparsing().a1);
   }
 }
```

Hi When I tried to extract data from excel sheet illegal forward reference error comes in the file object creation.

How to resolve this?

Comment: If the comment in the code is the question, when do you get it? From where? As an exception? It sure isn't a concept of javac to throw illegal forward references in the face of the user. If it is an exception it is probably very related to the xls-file which we don't have access to.

Comment: This error comes when i tried to compile the code

Comment: Can you show the compiler error?

Comment: after doing the correction that erickson mentioned, consider putting the code in a constructor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Illegal forward Reference java issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624919/illegal-forward-reference-java-issue)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

"Illegal forward reference" means that you are trying to use a variable before it is defined.

In this case, you are trying to invoke a method on `wb` in the declaration of `wb`.

```
Workbook wb = wb.getWorkbook(...);
```

Comment: Looks like getWorkbook is static in the API so: Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(...); should do the trick

Comment: Ah, I Googled around to try to figure out what API he's using but couldn't find an exact match.

Comment: JExcelAPI: http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/current/docs/jxl/Workbook.html

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the intention was to call 'statically' the `getWorkbook()` method, as you should. So, you should change your `wb` member initialization as:

```
Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Forward Illegal Reference is a term which comes into picture when an uninitialized non global variable value is assigned to a global variable.

In your case `Workbook wb = wb.getWorkbook(new File("----"));` - `wb` is uninitialized before calling the `getWorkbook()` method. For avoiding the FIR you should initialize `wb`.

Answer (score 0):

An "illegal forward reference" error in Java typically occurs when you're trying to reference a variable or method before it has been declared or initialized. This can happen in various contexts, such as within a class, method, or block of code.

**Here's an example of how this error might occur:**

```
public class Example {
    int x = y; // Illegal forward reference because 'y' is declared later
    int y = 5;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example example = new Example();
        System.out.println(example.x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

although getWorkbook is static, so accordingly, this code should have worked. But here, using the reference before its declaration or in the same statement as declaration is causing error "Forward referencing i.e. using reference before declaration".

Comment: `Getworkbook` might be static, but `wb` isn't.
You still can't call a static method on an uninitialised reference.