# Get jDateChooser date to jLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jcalendar, jdatechooser

This is my infernal problem. nowadays i'm trying to create my project according to my Degree. I already have added **jcalender** to my project in netbeans, and i already added jDateChooser to my jFrame. my problem is, when i chooseing a date from **jDateChooser** how will display this date on a jLabel. i tried to using `jLabel1.setText(jDateChooser1);` but in this case error will occur.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXeYO.jpg

Comment: What is `jDateChooser1`? Please, post the code related to the problem.

Comment: @Christian `JDateChooser` is a date picker from the [`JCalendar`](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/) library

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you need to get the date from the component, something like...

```
Date date = jDateChooser1.getDate();
```

Next you need to format that `Date` value to a `String`

```
String strDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date);
```

Finally, you need to set that value as the text for the lable...

```
jLabel1.setText(strDate);
```

If you have particular formatting requirements, you may need to look at [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Date date = jDateChooser1.getDate(); line says "illegal forward reference". what to do?

Comment: It's possible that `jDateChooser1` has not yet being defined, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746758/illegal-forward-reference-in-java)

Comment: by using (Property)ChangeListener

Answer (score 5):

```
String date  = ((JTextField)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
jLabel1.setText(date);
```

Answer (score 5):

import this file>>

```
      import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
```

Try this code >>

```
    SimpleDateFormat dcn = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String date = dcn.format(jDateChooser1.getDate() );
    jLabel1.setText(date.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = sdf.format(jDateChooser1.getSelectedDate().getTime());
jLabel1.setText(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String date1 = ((JTextField) jDateChooser4.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText() + "";
jLabel1.setText(date1);
```

Comment: Please edit to add a small explanation of what this code does.