# Return the Value of Date from JDateChooser

Tags: java, user-interface, jdatechooser

So I have made a GUI application where I have 3 TextFields and 1 JDateChooser. During runtime I want to check whether or not the user has typed anything into the Components. If they haven't typed anything I want to show an error message.

The Code I've tried :-

```
if (!cardnumb1.equals("") || !pin1.equals("") || !call1.equals("") || !fname1.equals(""))
        {
            verify1.setVisible(true);
        }

        if (cardnumb2.equals("") || pin2.equals("") || cal12.equals("") || fname2.equals(""))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"error");
        }
```

Where cardnumb1,pin1,fname1 are textFields and call1 is JDateChooser

The  `cal12.equals("")` throws a `.equals() on incomparable String types`

My declaration of Datatype for call1 is

```
Date call1 = date1.getDate();
```

Comment: It's not a string, so you can't compare it to a string, any more than you can compare the number 5 to an orange. Use a debugger to see what it actually returns if the user hasn't changed it.

Comment: I am new to java coding. Would please provide me with a link on how to do it?

Comment: Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21012875/4725875).