# Can I define a final variable with another final?

Tags: java, final

This is more of a hypothetical question but if I have some final called A and another final B that are both ints, I can't do this:

```
private final int A = B/2, B = (some kind of other derived number);
```

I am just wondering why. Any help would be awesome. NetBeans popped up an error on this and I just want to know why it is a problem.

PS-The error that popped up said "illegal forward reference".

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing variable `B` before you declare it. That's the reason for `"illegal forward reference".`

Define variable `B` before `A`

```
private final int B = (some kind of other derived number), A = B/2;
```

Comment: Now that I think about it, that makes a ton of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Pretend you're the compiler:

`private final int` ok. Mr user wants a "const" int

`A` the variable is called A

`=` ...here comes the value

`B/2` HUH? WHAT THE HELL IS B? NO ONE TOLD ME ANYTHING ABOUT B. STUFF YOU USER. I'M OUT OF HERE...

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers don't answer the underlying question:

> Why can I use methods that are defined later in my source file, but does the same with variables cause a *forward reference* error message?

The answer is found in the JLS, more specifically [JLS $12.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1)

> **The static initializers and class variable initializers are executed in textual order**, and may not refer to class variables declared in the class whose declarations appear textually after the use, even though these class variables are in scope ([§8.3.2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.3)). This restriction is designed to detect, at compile time, most circular or otherwise malformed initializations.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered here. Basically it means that you are trying to use a variable that is not initiated.

Initialize B first, then use it to initialize A

```
private final int B = ?, A = B/2;
```

[illegal forward reference in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746758/illegal-forward-reference-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't failing because A and B are final. It's failing because B isn't declared/initialized yet. If you declare it first, you'll be able to use them just fine.

For example,

```
private final int C = 5;
private final int B = C/3;
private final int A = B/2;
```

This is fine because B is declared first :)

"final" just means that you can't change the variable. So something like this **won't** work

```
private final static int C = 5;
private final static int B = C/3;
private final static int A = B/2;

public static void main (String[] args) {
    A = 5;
}
```

because now we're trying to modify A which is "final"