# Cannot reference a variable before it is defined - Java

Tags: java, reference

```
public class Wrapper {

    public Wrapper(final String name, final String email) {

        _name= name;
        _email = email;
    }

    private static final Card testCard = new Card(_email, _name);

    private final static String _name;
    private final static String _email;
    }
```

I would like the instantiate this class providing a name and an email.

I am getting "Cannot reference a variable before it is defined for (_email, _name) variables on line :

```
    private static final Card testCard = new Card(_email, _name);
```

I can make it work by moving the declarations to the top but is there any other way?

Thanks

Comment: What do you think your codes does? Do you know what `static` is?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm more thrown by the `final`s, personally, given that the OP is trying to modify the values. =/

Comment: I don't see how you've made it work just by moving the declarations.  I ran into a number of other problems when I tried it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I don't think you want to use `static`.

> I would like the instantiate this class providing a name and an email.

That means that you provide a name and an e-mail when creating an *instance* of the class.  But using `static` means that there is only *one* name and *one* e-mail, that **all** instances of the class share!  Unless every person in your universe has the same name and the same e-mail address, that is not what you want.  So get rid of `static` on `_name`, `_email`, and `testCard`.

Also, initializing `testCard` outside the constructor won't work, because the program will try to do `new Card(_email, _name)` before `_email` and `_name` have been initialized.  So change that to

```
private final Card testCard;
```

and in the constructor:

```
testCard = new Card(_email, _name);
```

*after* `_email` and `_name` have been set.

If you do this, you should be able to put the declarations anywhere you want.  The "Cannot reference a variable before it is defined" or "Illegal forward reference" problems only come up when you have global (static) variables, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746758/illegal-forward-reference-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

You cann't initialize `static` field because variables `_email` and `_name` are not initialized yet. You should initialize `testCard` after `_email` and `_name` will be initialized.

For example, you can do it in constructor

```
public Wrapper(final String name, final String email) 
{
    _name= name;
    _email = email;
    testCard = new Card(_email, _name);
}

private static Card testCard;
```

or separate method for it

```
public static void initialize(String name, String email)
{
    _name= name;
    _email = email;
    testCard = new Card(_email, _name);
}
```

Also you should remove `final` modifiers if you want to initialize `static` in contructor.