# Illegal forward reference while importing a package class in Android

Tags: android

As title suggests, illegal forward reference I have already seen already posted posts those are belonging to java code. But in my case, I am having issue in package import. Everything was fine perfectly but suddenly I don't know what happened to Android Studio, it started showing me below error

```
error: illegal forward reference
```

When I checked build area of Android Studio section under Java compiler and double clicked the error it took me to below packed import statement.

```
import com.abacusoft.util.AppController;
```

What is missing or wrong in it? Any help?

My AppController class extending Application class as mentioned below

```
public class AppController extends Application
```

**EDIT: Below is my complete AppController class**

```
package com.abacusoft.util;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import com.abacusoft.services.CallReceivingService;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue; 
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class AppController extends Application {
public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private static SharedPreferences preferences;

private static AppController mInstance;
private boolean isAppRunningFirstTime = true;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
    preferences = this.getSharedPreferences(AppSharedPref.APP_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

}

@Override
public void onTerminate() {
    super.onTerminate();
    stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CallReceivingService.class));
}

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

//Get Shared Preference
public SharedPreferences getPreferences() {
    return preferences;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}


public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, Object tag) {
    req.setTag(tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);

}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}

public boolean isAppRunningFirstTime() {
    return isAppRunningFirstTime;
}

public void setAppRunningFirstTime(boolean appRunningFirstTime) {
    isAppRunningFirstTime = appRunningFirstTime;
}
```

}

Comment: are you initializing any variables in declarators ? (maybe just post the entire AppController class)

Comment: I have updated my code  of AppController class @jonathanHeindl

Comment: @jonathanHeindl what is declarators?

Comment: something I more or less just made up ... I meant variables you instance on class instantiation (like TAG in your example) / compilation maybe  like in this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746758/illegal-forward-reference-in-java

Comment: in what class are you using the import statement ?

Comment: This is android service class

Comment: but it was working fine couple of minutes ago like TAG I was using before as well.

Comment: does a similar structure exist for AppController ins your service class ?

Comment: oh i think I know

Comment: please share what you know :(

Comment: sry I tohught I was fast enough to write it as answer ^^

Answer (score 0):

you are probably calling AppController.getInstance not on the class but on the instance you want to create

something like `AppController appController=appController.getinstance()`should be

```
AppController appController=AppController.getinstance()
```

capital A

Comment: hmm let me check and confirm

Comment: compiler error is taking me to import statemtent. As I said when I doudble click on java compile section for error. it is taking me to import statement with background highleted with yellow color

Comment: where are you calling getInstance ? can you give an example ?

Comment: I am calling getinstance method in many places in android service

Comment: like this AppController.getInstance().isAppRunningFirstTime()

Comment: I directly call getinstance and on that instance I am calling any method that is required

Comment: weird that should just get you a null pointer oO since you never create an Instance of AppController oO (or did you make sure onCreate ran before calling tihs)

Comment: dear I am not getting any exception while compiling I am facing this issue

Comment: nope - maybe it help to remember what you changed since the last time it worked oO

Comment: I have found this Reformat with Rearrange Entries can create illegal forward reference via this link https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+14+138.1503.3+Release+Notes
can you help me with this ?